# Nautilus not showing thumbnails for PNG files

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails, png, previews

My Nautilus file-manager does not show a preview of PNG files.

Ubuntu Version: **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS**

Nautilus Version: **GNOME nautilus 3.26.4**

I have tried various "solutions" form the web like :

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.thumbnails
```

or

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/cache/.thumbnails
```

or

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.thumbnails/* ~/.cache/thumbnails/*
```

After the last command I do not get any thumbnails for other files as JPG, BLEND, TIF and more.

I also looked at the *Preferences* from Nautilus which configure to only show files smaller than 4 GB. But all the files I'm concerned about are way smaller than 4 GB.

How can I configure Nautilus to show Thumbnails for all these file types?

Answer (score 4):

It might be the package `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin` missing. First you can check if it's installed with:

```
dpkg -s libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin
```

If not installed, then you can just install it:

```
sudo apt install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin
```

If you have dconf-editor please also check the values for `org / desktop / thumbnailers` and make sure your file type is not disabled in there.